# How to convert string array to const char **?

Tags: c++

I was think something like:

```
const char * res[cnt];
int i = 0;
for (auto mystring : strings) {
    const char * str = mystring.c_str();
    res[i++] = str;
}
```

//then pass res as const char **

But it occurred to me that 'str' is a local variable, the address stored in res could be invalid? What is the right way to do so?

Comment: the contents of the loop are semanticall incorrect as you fill the array with a bunch of dangling pointers

Comment: It would improve the question to show a complete program. The answer very much depends on what `strings` is, what its lifetime is, and what you are going to do with `res`. and what `cnt` is

Comment: You're making copies of the strings with `auto` instead of `auto &`, so there may indeed be an issue.

Comment: Note that this isn't "converting" the strings, just putting their internal string addresses into the other array. This creates an issue: when the strings have to reallocate and thus possibly change their address as a result, the pointers in the arrays may become dangling pointers. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/fvob3hfxT

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 thanks I see the risk. But what is the right way? I just want to pass these strings and they will be processed. The problem is I need to pass a const char ** since API limitation..

Comment: @Michael I suppose you could create an array of pointers to heap memory and copy everything to that, so the strings pointed to by the `char *`s will remain as is until you free them. Or just keep it like this and not modify the strings at all after the `for` loop until `res` is completely useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with `str`, which will be destroyed after iteration, but this doens't mean the `char` array pointed by it will be destroyed too.

The problem is `mystring` is declared as by-copy, it'll be destroyed after iteration, then the `char` arrays returned by `c_str` get destroyed too. Pointers assigned into `res` become dangling.

You can change `mystring` as reference (to `const`), e.g.

```
for (auto const & mystring : strings) {
    const char * str = mystring.c_str();
    res[i++] = str;
}
```